# RegEX to match unicode Java Escaped characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which finds all unicodes and removes it.

Example:

> \ud83e \udd80

When I do this:`[^\u0000-\u007F]`, it matches the actual single unicode character.

What I am trying to match is the actual backslash with the five characters in front

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to match every string that look like `\u0002`, you can use this regex

```
\\[0-9a-zA-Z]{5}
```

I'm not sure if that's what you wanted but you can test more cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/bwk29Q/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `\\u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4,6}`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GajwQM/2)